# Python 3 GUI program

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface

I am trying to write a function in Python3 GUI where

- User inputs three different readings and clicks 'continue'
- Each reading needs to be a positive float/int
- If the above format is not received an error message is displayed in a label "text"
- once the readings are valid my function is to calculate the total of each reading and display the largest value on the GUI.

This is my code but I'm not sure how to return the values of each reading and return the highest value using another function.

```
def num_o():    try:
        O = float(o_entry.get())
        T = (50 * O)/6
        Ta = ("%0.2f" % (T))
        answer["text"]= 'Total:', str(Ta)
        assert O > 0
    except AssertionError:
        answer.config(text="Invalid Entry")
    except ValueError:
        answer.config(text="Invalid Entry")
    return answer

def num_s():

    try:
        S = float(s_entry.get())
        T1 = (20 * S)/2
        Tb = ("%0.2f" % (T1))
        answer["text"]= 'Total:', str(Tb)
        assert S > 0
    except AssertionError:
        answer.config(text="Invalid Entry")
    except ValueError:
        answer.config(text="Invalid Entry")
    return answer

def num_p():
    try:
        P = float(p_entry.get())
        T2 = (25 * P)/3
        Tc = ("%0.2f" % (T2))
        answer["text"]= 'Total:', str(Tc)
        assert P > 0
    except AssertionError:
        answer.config(text="Invalid Entry")
    except ValueError:
        answer.config(text="Invalid Entry")
    return answer
    
answer["text"]= 'Total:', str(Ta + Tb + Tc) # not sure how to return the highest value and display as a label
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Python3 GUI"? Tkinter?

Comment: yes that correct

Comment: yes tkinter on python 3

Comment: The code is incomplete. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Need help in returning the value and displaying the largest number